# AngularJS dropdown multiselect not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, web

I wanted to create a simple multi-select dropdown which displays days (mon,tue...sun), select all, unselect all...using angular JS, bootstrap,JS.

I wanted to write controller in a way that if i select monday twice, it de-selects and remove it from the selected items....instead it is keep on adding the elements again and again...and unselect all is not working.

I tried every other way and couldn't succeed. Plz help me or share any similar code that can give me a idea.

PS: I don't want to use jQuery for this.

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: No actually, I edited so much and couldn't get the initial version that I created.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following:

https://github.com/sebastianha/angular-bootstrap-multiselect

OR

http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

The second link seems to be exactly what you are looking for.